# Haskell Esqueleto project to list of records instead of tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples, record, esqueleto

In all the examples I have seen the results from [esqueleto](https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto/blob/master/test/Common/Test.hs) are projected into a list of tuples. This makes coding and maintenance harder because of lack of labels.

For example:

```
previousLogItems <- select $ from $ \li -> do
        orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
        limit 10
        return (li ^. LogItemId, li ^. LogItemTitle)
```

Is there any way to get esqueleto to project the results to a list of records instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you construct the tuple yourself. Indeed:

```
previousLogItems <- select $ from $ \li -> do
        orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
        limit 10
        return (li ^. LogItemId, li ^. LogItemTitle)
```

You thus make use of the [**`(^.) :: (PersistEntity val, PersistField typ) => expr (Entity val) -> EntityField val typ -> expr (Value typ)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.3/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#v:-94-.) "selector" to obtain the fields and wrap them into a tuple.

If you write it like:

```
previousLogItems >- select $ from $ \li -> do
        orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
        limit 10
        return li
```

You will obtain a list of `[Entity Foo]` where `Foo` is the type of object you query.

You can use the [**`entityVal :: Entity a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-0.8.0.2/docs/Database-Persist.html#t:Entity) to obtain the entity that is wrapped into the `Entity`, for example:

```
previousLogItems <- select $ from $ \li -> do
        orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
        limit 10
        return li
mapM_ (print . entityVal) previousLogItems
```

given the entity is of course an instance of `Show`.

Comment: I asked the wrong question. I'll create another one regarding projections. Thank you very much, this is great answer

Comment: This is what I wanted to ask, if you happen to know a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50143910/750216