# Haskell Esqueleto project subset of columns to list of custom records

Tags: haskell, tuples, record, esqueleto

In all the examples I have seen the results from [esqueleto](https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto/blob/master/test/Common/Test.hs) are projected into a list of tuples or to [entities records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50143591/750216).

For example:

```
previousLogItems <- select $ from $ \li -> do
        orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
        limit 10
        return (li ^. LogItemId, li ^. LogItemTitle)
```

Is there any way in esqueleto to project a subset of the columns to custom  records (different than the entity) instead of tuples? This being done without an extra projection from tuples to custom records.

As an example, let's say that it would be inefficient to get all the data from the database so we only want to project columns WindowTitle and BeginTime from the database into a custom record with adequate names for those columns.

**Update**

Example of not working code:

```
data Custom = Custom
  { title :: Text
  , id    :: Int
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

daily :: Servant.Handler [Custom]
daily = do
  lis <- liftIO $ runDB $
            select $ from $ \li -> do
                    orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
                    limit 25
                    return (Custom (li ^. LogItemTitle) (li ^. LogItemId))
  return lis
```

Error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’
              with actual type ‘SqlExpr (Database.Esqueleto.Value Text)’
• In the first argument of ‘Custom’, namely ‘(li ^. LogItemTitle)’
  In the first argument of ‘return’, namely
    ‘(Custom (li ^. LogItemTitle) (li ^. LogItemId))’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    return (Custom (li ^. LogItemTitle) (li ^. LogItemId))
```

**Update**

Example of not working code:

```
daily :: Servant.Handler [Custom]
daily = do
  lis <- liftIO $ runDB $
            select $ from $ \li -> do
                    orderBy [desc (li ^. LogItemId)]
                    limit 25
                    return (Custom <$> (li ^. LogItemTitle) <*> (li ^. LogItemId))
  return lis
```

Error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Database.Esqueleto.Value Text’ with ‘Text’
  Expected type: SqlExpr Text
    Actual type: SqlExpr (Database.Esqueleto.Value Text)
• In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘(li ^. LogItemTitle)’
  In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
    ‘Custom <$> (li ^. LogItemTitle)’
  In the first argument of ‘return’, namely
    ‘(Custom <$> (li ^. LogItemTitle) <*> (li ^. LogItemId))’


• Couldn't match type ‘Database.Esqueleto.Value (Key LogItem)’
                 with ‘Int’
  Expected type: SqlExpr Int
    Actual type: SqlExpr (Database.Esqueleto.Value (Key LogItem))
• In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘(li ^. LogItemId)’
  In the first argument of ‘return’, namely
    ‘(Custom <$> (li ^. LogItemTitle) <*> (li ^. LogItemId))’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    return (Custom <$> (li ^. LogItemTitle) <*> (li ^. LogItemId))
```

Comment: Can't we here perform an `fmap`?

Comment: I think you might have to instantiate [SqlSelect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.3/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Internal-Sql.html#t:SqlSelect). I'd maybe look at the way the tuple instances are defined and go from there.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am asking of a way to specifically return custom records directly. Without the inefficiency of going tuple and then to the custom type.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking something like `Custom <$> (li ^. LogItemTitle) <*> (li ^. LogItemId)`. But right now I can not test it :(

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think lifting it will be enough. `select :: (SqlSelect a r, MonadIO m) => SqlQuery a -> SqlReadT m [r]`, from what I can tell there's an actual translation from the return type `a` to an SQL expression to the final type `r`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried your example and it is also not working. See last update.

Answer (score 2):

What esqueleto is actually doing here is a little complicated. Here is the type for `select`:

```
select :: (SqlSelect a r, MonadIO m) => SqlQuery a -> SqlReadT m [r]
```

This takes an `SqlQuery a` (a monad wrapping the value you `return`), and returns an `SqlReadT m [r]` (a monad wrapping a list of results). When you `return` your `Custom` type, the following happens:

1. esqueleto converts your `a` type to persistent's internal SQL representation
2. persistent executes the query and gets back a results list
3. esqueleto converts the results list from persistent's internal SQL representation to `[r]`

---

To make this work for custom types, you'll need to instantiate [SqlSelect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.3/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Internal-Sql.html#t:SqlSelect), and define conversion functions to and from the persistent types:

```
data Custom' = Custom' (Value Text) (Value Int)

data Custom = Custom
  { title :: Text
  , id    :: Int
  }

instance SqlSelect Custom' Custom where
  sqlSelectCols esc (Custom' a b) = (mconcat [ta, ", ", tb], va ++ vb)
    where
      (ta, va) = sqlSelectCols esc a
      (tb, vb) = sqlSelectCols esc b
  sqlSelectColCount _ = 2
  sqlSelectProcessRow [PersistText a, PersistInt64 b] = Right $ Custom a b
  sqlSelectProcessRow _ = Left "Error: Incorrect rows to translate to Custom"
```

(note that I wasn't actually able to test any of the above, so it might have bugs)

One thing to note is that in the above example, the `a` and `r` types are not the same (`Custom'` vs `Custom`). This is because inside of a `select`, all of the values you're working with are of type `Value`, not their actual types.